# Is HHOOK process-specific in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, win32-process

We are using SetWindowsHookEx to hook to another process B from our process A. This function returns HHOOK which can be used by UnhookWindowsHookEx to remove the hook. If our process A which installed the hook crashed, can I use the same HHOOK value from another process to remove the hook from process B?

Comment: Doesn't windows remove it automatically?

Comment: From which another process? Process C ?

Comment: Yes, process C, correct.